# Actionscript-3 to Actionscript-2 fix syntax

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, actionscript-2, gsap

is it possible to fix this to work in "as2"? The console tells me the error is in the line of "for"

```
import com.greensock.*;

var images:Array = [mc0,mc1,mc2,mc3];

var tl:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1});

for (var i:int = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    tl.from(images[i],1,{alpha:0})
    .addLabel("image" + i)
    .to(images[i], 0, {alpha:0}, "+=1");
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please always post the exact error messages in case you receive any, even if the problem might be obvious.

Comment: @ndm The problem is in "i:int". In AS2 must use number, not int

Comment: I know that, I was just saying that when asking questions, post the _exact_ error messages that you are receiving.

Comment: So is this question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I replace ":int" by ":Number" and "alpha" -> "_alpha"

Thank you!